# GWT CellTable interact with enter key

Tags: java, gwt, keyboard

Hello I have a CellTable I want to select an element within a cell when I press Enter on the keyboard or when I click the mouse.

The problem is that when I press the key nothing happens

This is my code that enables the enter key functionality on the celltable

```
 CellTable<Value> table = new CellTable<Value>();

    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Value> event) {
                    if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) { // operation}
```

This is also the functionality for the mouse click

```
.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
                        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
```

My problem is that pressing "enter" on the keyboard will not run at first, but runs when I select it and then press enter.

Please help.

Comment: How will you know to which cell the 'enter' is associated, if there is no cell selected? I didn't understand your question. Could you explain better?

Comment: my problem is if i press spacebar it run if i click enter key not run

Answer (score 0):

CellPreviewEvent gives you any event that get fired on the cell. Unless you select a cell, it is not fired. So first you need to select a cell through keyboard navigation or mouse before pressing enter

Comment: i dont' understand can give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple enough.

When you press "enter" an Event is raised on your computer and so it does for your browser.

The event is propagated to the "ACTIVE" elements. That is if you have an open browser and the Console, and the active window (the Focused one) is up front, nothing will happen on the browser if your press "enter" and the cmd console will change a line.

Same thing happens on a webApp. When something has **FOCUS** then and only then can it do something with the click/key event.

For example: Open a web mail such as hotmail/gmail etc. Click anywhere inside the page (not the textboxes). Press Enter (nothing happens). Click inside a textbox (username or password). Press Enter. Notice that something happens. Why? Because the object the Understands the Event is now focused (active).

If you want it to happen on Load of the view, then you can explicitly set the focus on the item on load (though this will not achieve what you want).

Comment: how can set focus on each cell? when i press tab each cell become yellow but is not a focus

Comment: When your view/page is loaded you can use the table.setFocus(true) method of the celltable after the celltable is constructed and added to the page (the CellTable implements the Focusable interface). Same thing applies for the Cells (though not 100% sure).

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onBrowserEvent` for the ID column in your `CellTable`, checking for the ENTER pressed:

```
    Column<T, Boolean> idCol = new Column<T, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell()) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(T obj) {
            return selectionModel.isSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, T object, NativeEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                selectionModel.setSelected(object, !selectionModel.isSelected(item));
                return;
            }
            super.onBrowserEvent(context, elem, object, event);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You should not disable keyboardSelectionPolicy first.

2- You should add this block to constructor or onLoad method:

```
table.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<GuiltyAccusationInfoDto>() {
@Override
public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<GuiltyAccusationInfoDto> event) {
    if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_UP || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN
            || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_RIGHT
            || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_PAGEUP || event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_PAGEDOWN) {
        selectionModel.setSelected(listOfData.get(table.getKeyboardSelectedRow()), true);
    }
}});
```